# Design Suggestion Unsubscribe link in an E-mail

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I need some suggestions to see how we can handle a situation to implement an unsubscribe link.

Here's what we have 
1. A Web API 2 project with no UI..servers as an rest api to do all our backend work.
2. Windows service with multiple jobs to send notifications (Consumes the web api2 Solution)
3. We also have a MVC4 solution that actually Host out UI and all the UI interaction goes through it and it is also consuming the web api2 solution.

We Want to implement an unsubscribe link on one of the Notifications sent by the windows service.

The problem:
- We have to redirect the unsubscribe link to an page to show messages (Success/Fail)
- Our Web API 2 has no UI.
- Also we have Basic Auth implemented on the API and it expects user credentials for all the calls and designer don't any calls that are not authorized.

How can we safely pass the credentials from the unsibscribe link if we are directly calling the API? 
if we are directly calling the API where to host the page to show success/failure?

Is there any other way to implement it and what would be the best way to design the solution?

Any Suggestions would be useful?

Answer (score 2):

You generate the unique link and you store it in a table against a user id. The page which responds to the link should be part of your MVC web project where you will read this unique string and use that to query this table which tells you what user is executing this GET request. If you really want the user information, query your user table with this user id. Other wise, simply call the method which deletes the subscription record from your table. You may keep this method in a common service project which the Web project has a reference to.